# Add student status to Apple store app

Tags: ios, apple-store

I am a student who also has the iOS Apple Store App on their iPhone.

Is there a way in viewing and buying products with a student discount through the app or can I only use my student discount on apple.com/uk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible to use the education store on the Apple Store app and you'll need to use the website.

Comment: As I thought. Oh well, least I have a laptop.